# Writing QString to Excel produce extra Tab?

Tags: c++, excel, qt, csv, qtextstream

After working with my initial Data.CSV, I want to save it again as Data.CSV, while that works already amazingly well, it somehow writes in the wrong Column when I open it in Excel.

Somehow wrongly written Data:

[image: Somehow wrongly written Data]

That is how I write it to the File:

```
QFile file(fileName);
QString DataFullConvert;
DataFullConvert = DataFullConvert.trimmed();
qDebug() << DataFullConvert;
if (!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text)){
    qDebug() << file.errorString();
}
else{
    QTextStream stream(&file);
    stream << DataFullConvert;
```

That's how my qDebug() looks like: qDebug Output:
[image: qDebug Output]

I noticed always that qt is doing a `newline` before the Strings I changed (*the 8-digit Numbers*).

I tried already using `trimmed();`, but the Outcome was the same. Any Ideas what it could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get rid of the semi-colons after the newline characters. When Excel sees the newline character, it assumes a new row starts, and then it sees the semi-colon, which creates the first empty column.

```
DataFullConvert.replace(QString("\n;"), QString("\n"));
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved the Problem, much appreciated for that help :)

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider upvoting and marking the answer correct.